# Decompile APK and export code source project

Tags: android, apk

friends i hope,  to help me,

I need to know how to decompile apk and export code source project to run in android studio and rebuild it,

Thanks guys,  :)

Comment: See my github project https://github.com/russell-shizhen/DecompileApk#steps

Answer (score 0):

Try these links

http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

https://www.apkdecompilers.com/

Decompiling an APK, doesn't provide gradle code. It only provides java & resource code with some encryptions. You can not run that code in Android Studio, but you can use some of the code in your own project.